# Apollo Client "Named export 'remove' not found"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo-client, nuxtjs3

I'm attempting to create an `apollo client` plugin for a `Nuxt 3` application. It's currently throwing an error regarding a package called `ts-invariant`:

```sh
file:///Users/[my name]/Repositories/[project]/node_modules/@apollo/client/utilities/globals/fix-graphql.js:1
import { remove } from "ts-invariant/process/index.js";
         ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'remove' not found. The requested module 'ts-invariant/process/index.js' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'ts-invariant/process/index.js';
const { remove } = pkg;

    at ModuleJob._instantiate (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:124:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:181:5)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:281:24)
    at async __instantiateModule__ (file:///Users/[my name]/Repositories/[project]/.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:4550:3)
[vite dev] Error loading external "/Users/[my name]/Repositories/[project]/node_modules/@apollo/client/core/index.js".
  at file://./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:3170:289  
  at async __instantiateModule__ (file://./.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:4550:3)
```

**I feel like I know enough about this error to know it has something to do with how Nuxt 3 deals with ESM, but I can't be for certain.**

Here's the nuxt plugin: 
`plugins/apollo-client.js`

```js
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from "#app"
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client/core"
import { DefaultApolloClient } from "@vue/apollo-composable"

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()
  const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    uri: config.PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  })
  nuxtApp.vueApp.provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient)
})
```

In a normal scenario, I might use the nuxt-apollo community module, but it is currently afk regarding a `nuxt 3` port, so a plugin it is.

Here's some documentation I relied on for my plugin:
https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/setup.html#vue-3
https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/plugins

Comment: I've made some progress by manually altering the package.json: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/287#issuecomment-1065845661
The lack of exports (in the latest version 3.5.10 I've tested) in @apollo/client and ts-invariant might cause this for Weback 5 based builds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by including `@apollo/client` and `ts-invariant/process` into the nuxt build transpile like so:

```js
  // nuxt.config.js
  // ...
  build: {
    postcss: {
      postcssOptions: require('./postcss.config.js')
    },
    transpile: [
      '@apollo/client',
      'ts-invariant/process',
    ],
  },
  // ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've pinpointed the underlying issue. Apollo Client (3.5.10 at the time of writing early 2022) is using `"module":"index.js"` to declare the path of the ESM exports.
However it seems that Webpack 5 based bundlers do not support this. Using `exports` in the package.json fixes it for good for me.

You should upvote [this feature request](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/287).

And here is my palliative until then, [using a small script to alter the package.json](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/287#issuecomment-1065851982).

Comment: I'm currently using Vite instead of Webpack, but thanks for contributing!

Comment: And Vite handles this out of the box?

Comment: No it doesn't sadly

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here worked for me. I had to add this `include` as well.

```
{
    test: /\.m?js$/,
    resolve: {
      fullySpecified: false,
    },
    include: [
      'graphql',
    ].map((name) => new RegExp(`node_modules/${name}`)),
  },
```