# @apollo/client using svelte "Named export 'remove' not found."

Tags: node.js, apollo-client, sveltekit

Like [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70615613/apollo-client-named-export-remove-not-found), same error is occurring while using svelte kit.

here is the error:

```
import { remove } from "ts-invariant/process/index.js";
         ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'remove' not found. The requested module 'ts-invariant/process/index.js' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'ts-invariant/process/index.js';
const { remove } = pkg;
```

I'm using the current version(^3.5.10) of @apollo/client, and using the beta version(^3.6.0-beta.6) gets other error; while using `import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from '@apollo/client/core/index.js'`, it gets:

```
Directory import '/node_modules/@apollo/client/core' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /node_modules/svelte-apollo/dist/svelte-apollo.js
```

or if I use `import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from '@apollo/client/core'`, it gets:

```
Directory import 'node_modules/@apollo/client/core' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from node_modules/svelte-apollo/dist/svelte-apollo.js
Did you mean to import @apollo/client/core/core.cjs?
```

or if I use `import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql } from '@apollo/client/core/core.cjs'` it just says

```
exports is not defined
```

Comment: Same issue with Next, did you ever solve this?

Comment: @EricBurel Not yet.

Comment: I've put a bounty on the issue you linked that was solved for Nuxt